# Using SetValue to add an event handler

Tags: .net, wpf, event-handling, setvalue

This code works

```
TextBlock tbTest = new TextBlock();
tbTest.MouseRightButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(cc_CopyToClip);
```

But I need to do the same thing with a SetValue
This does not work - compiler error

```
FrameworkElementFactory textblock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
textblock.SetValue(TextBlock.MouseRightButtonDownEvent, += new MouseButtonEventHandler(cc_CopyToClip));
```

How to assign an event handler via SetValue?

Answer

```
textblock.AddHandler(TextBlock.MouseRightButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(cc_CopyToClip));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not dependency property to use `SetValue`. You could use [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to add routed event handler.

Answer (score 11):

To assign/unassign routed event handler [`FrameworkElementFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` methods. So your call should look like this:

```
textblock.AddHandler(TextBlock.MouseRightButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(cc_CopyToClip));
```